# VLAN can't access to the common router

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have bought a TP-Link Manageable switch and I like to make 2 differents networks with only one router/web box.
My router is a Livebox pro v3 and followed this tutorial to make VLAN :
https://www.tp-link.com/fr/FAQ-570.html

My rules are :

- Computers of VLAN `Private 1` can communicate between us
- Computers of VLAN `Private 2` can communicate between us
- Computers of VLAN `Private 1` can't communicate with `Private 2`
- Computers of VLAN `Private 1` and `Private 2` can communicate with the router

It's wired like this :

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 ... 8 | 9 ... 24 |
```

- 1 : it's reserved to configuration (not connected)
- 2 : another switch with computers of `Private 2`
- 3...8 : Common ports (one of them is the connection to Livebox router)
- 9 ... 24 : computers of `Private 1`

To do this, I created four VLAN :

- 1 : System (Ports 1 to 24)
- 100 : `Private 1` (Ports 3 to 24)
- 101 : `Private 2` (Ports 2 to 8)
- 102 : Common (Ports 2 to 24)

And Port Config it's :

```
| VLAN | Name        | Ports config | Link    | Rule  | PVID
| 1    | System      | 1            | GENERAL | UNTAG | 1
| 100  | `Private 1` | 9 to 24      | GENERAL | UNTAG | 100
| 101  | `Private 2` | 2            | GENERAL | UNTAG | 101
| 102  | Common      | 3 to 8       | GENERAL | UNTAG | 102
```

My problem is : computers of `Private 1` and `Private 2` receive an IP form the router but randomly can't access to the router and internet.

What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Your router will need 802.11q virtual interfaces created for this to work. You didn't add what ports are tagged untagged from the switch. Normally end devices are NOT tagged. Switch to switch or switch to router MUST be tagged.

Comment: I inquired, and my router is not  802.11q compatible :( How can I configure my TPlink T2600G to make router instead of the livebox ?

Comment: You could always build your own 802.11q router. Check out pfsense or opensense. They are both opensource (free). You could put it on an old laptop or tower. Since your using vlans you would only need one nic. (The trunk port)

Answer (score 2):

You’re not using trunk ports at all. Go back to the instructions you linked to. I can’t read the instructions, but it talks about trunk ports.

A trunk port typically contains tagged traffic from all vLANs. It is how devices that speak vLANs communicate with each other.

One port on the router and one port on the switch should be hooked together and configured as a trunk port. If you don’t have a specific mode called “trunk” then realize that the goal is to assign both networks (vLANs) as tagged on that port.

Your “common” vLAN serves no purpose and should be eliminated. You shouldn’t have more than one untagged vLAN assigned to any port.

I am assuming your router is properly configured otherwise, such as having two distinct interfaces on two distinct subnets that are used as a gateway address for machines on each vLAN. And, that DHCP services have been properly configured for each subnet.

Comment: I tested with TRUNK protocol but it doesn't work. My router is not compatible  802.11q ... thanks for the answer i will find another solution

Comment: Then alternatively you need to use two ports on the router. One port is connected to one vLAN on the switch, and other port is connected to the other vLAN on the switch. The router should have an interface for each subnet assigned to the corresponding port. All traffic should be untagged then. You cannot use a single cable between the router and switch if you can’t use 802.11q.

Comment: @appleoddity, The instructions have an English counter-part. These instructions are just for vlan switching, and do not even mention a vlan capable router. It seems like they are trying to give instructions for a multi lan router. But a good answer otherwise!